# Dissecting a binary file in C

Tags: c, binary

I'm working on assignment in which I need to dissect a binary file retrieve the source address from the header data. I was able to get hex data from the file to write out as we were instructed but I can't make heads or tails of what I am looking at. Here's the print out code I used.

```
FILE *ptr_myfile;
char buf[8];

ptr_myfile = fopen("packets.1","rb");
if (!ptr_myfile)
{
    printf("Unable to open file!");
    return 1;
}

size_t rb;
do {
    rb = fread(buf, 1, 8, ptr_myfile);
    if( rb ) {
        size_t i;
        for(i = 0; i < rb; ++i) {
                printf("%02x", (unsigned int)buf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 } while( rb );
```

And here's a small portion of the output:

```
120000003c000000
4500003c195d0000
ffffff80011b60ffffff8115250b
4a7d156708004d56
0001000561626364
65666768696a6b6c
6d6e6f7071727374
7576776162636465
666768693c000000
4500003c00000000
ffffffff01ffffffb5ffffffbc4a7d1567
ffffff8115250b00005556
0001000561626364
65666768696a6b6c
6d6e6f7071727374
7576776162636465
666768693c000000
4500003c195d0000
ffffff8001775545ffffffcfffffffbe29
ffffff8115250108004d56
0001000561626364
65666768696a6b6c
6d6e6f7071727374
7576776162636465
666768693c000000
4500003c195f0000
......
```

So we are using this diagram to aid in the assignment[image]

I'm really having difficulty translating information from the binary file to some thing useful that I can manage, and searching the website hasn't yielded me much. I just need some help putting me in the right direction.

Comment: Heh, this code works I didn't put all of it in there. The code is working as it should, I just don't know where to go from there

Comment: So, you know the byte ordering of the binary format, and the byte ordering of your platform (please confirm if they are the same or different), and buf is an array of unsigned char?  We don't like to play "The Great Creskin" here.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - (we need a compilable example).

Comment: I'm not old enough for that reference but I've added the rest of the code for that example

Comment: Also Its x86 system, so it's little endian I guess

Comment: Did you know that standard internet network byte order is big endian, for both IPV4 and IPv6? ( So are all non-Intel major CPU types that I am aware of on the market (HP, Sun, SGI, etc.  )  So, you'll need to handle that.  Note also the "header" section talks about 32-bit words... so you need to fix ordering (network to host) on words of that size before interpreting them, I'll bet.  (you are reading 64 bits at a shot with your fread).  See Beej's guide to network programming for an intro.  http://www.retran.com/beej/htonsman.html

Comment: Once you've taken care of that, you then can look at parts of the data in the `uint32_t` 32-bit word using bitmasks. I'm sure you can look that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you actually are reversing parts of an IP packet based on the diagram.  This diagram is based on 32-bit words, with each bit being shown as the small 'ticks' along the horizontal ruler looking thing at the top.  Bytes are shown as the big 'ticks' on the top ruler.

So, if you were to read the first byte of the file, the low-order nibble (the low-order four bytes) contains the version, and the high order nibble contains the number of 32-bit words in the header (assuming we can interpret this as an IP header).

So, from you diagram, you can see that the source address is in the fourth word so to read this, you can advance the file point to this point and read in four bytes. So in pseudo-code you should be able to do this:

```
    fp = fopen("the file name")
    fseek(fp, 12)                  // advance the file pointer 12 bytes
    fread(buf, 1, 4, fp)           // read in four bytes from the file.
```

Now you should have the source address in buf.

OK, to make this a bit more concrete, here is a packet I captured off my home network:

```
    0000   00 15 ff 2e 93 78 bc 5f f4 fc e0 b6 08 00 45 00  .....x._......E.
    0010   00 28 18 c7 40 00 80 06 00 00 c0 a8 01 05 5e 1f  .(..@.........^.
    0020   1d 9a fd d3 00 50 bd 72 7e e9 cf 19 6a 19 50 10  .....P.r~...j.P.
    0030   41 10 3d 81 00 00                                A.=...
```

The first 14 bytes are the EthernetII header, with the first six bytes `(00 15 ff 2e 93 78)` being the destination MAC address, the next six bytes `(bc 5f f4 fc e0 b6)` is the source MAC address and the new two bytes `(08 00)` denote that the next header is of type IP.

The next twenty bytes is the IP header (which you show in your figure), these bytes are:

```
    0000   45 00 00 28 18 c7 40 00 80 06 00 00 c0 a8 01 05  E..(..@.........
    0010   5e 1f 1d 9a                                      ^...
```

So to interpret this lets look at 4-byte words.

The first 4-byte word `(45 00 00 28)`, according to your figure is:

```
     first byte     : version & length, we have 0x45 meaning IPv4, and 5 4-byte words in length
     second byte    : Type of Service 0x00
     3rd & 4th bytes: total length 0x00 0x28 or 40 bytes.
```

The second 4-byte word `(18 c7 40 00)`, according to your figure is:

```
     1st & 2nd bytes: identification 0x18 0xc7
     3rd & 4th bytes: flags (3-bits) & fragmentation offset (13-bits)
                      flags - 0x02  0x40 is 0100 0000 in binary, and taking the first three bits 010 gives us 0x02 for the flags.
                      offset - 0x00
```

The third 4-byte word `(80 06 00 00)`, according to your figure is:

```
     first byte     : TTL, 0x80 or 128 hops 
     second byte    : protocol 0x06 or TCP
     3rd & 4th bytes: 0x00 0x00
```

The fourth 4-byte word `(c0 a8 01 05)`, according to your figure is:

```
     1st to 4th bytes:  source address, in this case 192.168.1.5
                        notice that each byte corresponds to one of the octets in the IP address.
```

The fifth 4-byte word `(5e 1f 1d 9a)`, according to your figure is:

```
     1st to 4th bytes: destination address, in this case 94.31.29.154
```

Doing this type of programming is a bit confusing at first, I recommend doing a paring by hand (like I did above) a few times to get the hang of it.

One final thing, in this line of code `printf("%02x", (unsigned int)buf[i]);`, I'd recommend changing it to `printf("%02x ", (unsigned char)buf[i]);`.  Remember that each element in you **buf** array represents a single byte read from the file.

Hope this helps,
T.

Comment: Wow that's very helpful! What about the lines like the 3rd and 11, 12th lines.  Are they some other data not part of the individual packets? They don't seem to fit the diagram

Comment: You are correct, which is why I suspect that you have a bug in your display code.  It would be helpful for you to open the original file in a hexeditor - I use frhed (on Windows) or Okteta or xxd (on Linux), just to check that your display code is correct.

Comment: Once I changed the print line to be a char instead of an int, those lines printed correctly